# ng-repeat only updating after clicking another tab or typing in a textbox

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, bootbox

I'm pretty new to angular and have been having a bit of a problem in trying to create a basic "to-do" list sort of app.

There are various categories in the sidebar, and the user can click a button that brings up a modal prompting the user for the name of a new category.  This name is used to create a new category, which is pushed onto the preexisting array.

However, the new category is only appearing after I start typing in another text-box on the screen or click on another tab.

The code that should be relevant:

```
var list = this;

$(document).on("click", ".prompt", function(e) {
bootbox.prompt("What do you want your new category to be?", function(result) {                
    if(result !== null) {
        list.addCategory(result);
    }
});
});

this.addCategory = function(result) {
  if(result.trim() != "") {
    var newCategory = new Category(result);
    list.categories.push(newCategory);
    this.setCategory(newCategory);
  }
};
```

I can't seem to figure out how to post HTML as a code block, but here's the directives used to list out the categories (with `categoryCtrl` being the controller in question):  `ng-class="{active: categoryCtrl.isSet(category) }" ng-repeat="category in categoryCtrl.categories" ng-init="categoryCtrl.currCategory = categoryCtrl.categories[0]"`

I know that the array is being updated immediately - if I add an alert 'bootbox.alert(list.categories[list.categories.length-1].name)' the alert gives me whatever the input was like it's supposed to.  It's just not showing up in the ng-repeat.

Another interesting observations is that the `ng-init` overrides the `this.setCategory(newCategory)` - so it seems that when the list does update, it is reverting to its `ng-init` value.

Other places where I have an ng-repeat of an array, it's updated automatically when something new is pushed onto it.  I'm wondering if it may have something to do with the modal/usage of bootbox - everywhere else things are added either by a checkbox or keying something into a textbox on screen, this is the only place where a modal is used.

Comment: try adding the push inside `$scope.$apply(function() { // here  })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working [plunker based on your code.](https://plnkr.co/edit/YfOEV9SjG2SwkV8ybGs3?p=preview)

The app looks like below. I initialize an array with dummy data for the example, but an empty array would work too. I used the vm = this syntax similar to what you have. When calling $nbBootbox.prompt it returns a promise so you need to use the then() syntax like below:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngBootbox']);

    app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$ngBootbox', function($scope, $ngBootbox) {
      var vm = this;

      vm.name = 'World';
      vm.categories = ['Category 1', 'Category 2'];

      vm.prompt = function() {

        $ngBootbox.prompt('Enter a new category?')
          .then(function(result) {
            console.log('Prompt returned: ' + result);
            vm.categories.push(result);
          }, function() {
            console.log('Prompt dismissed!');
          });

      }
    }]);
```

To make your HTML more angular like I changed it to this and also use the ControllerAs syntax:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">
  <p>Hello {{vm.name}} !</p>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="c in vm.categories">{{c}}</li>
  </ul>
  <a href="" ng-click="vm.prompt()">Add Category</a>
</body>
```

So, the link calls the prompt() function... it opens the modal and if you enter in the category, I push it to the categories array and it is added automatically to the page as a new bullet point in the list of categories.

[From the documentation](https://github.com/eriktufvesson/ngBootbox):
$ngBootbox.prompt(msg)

Returns a promise that is resolved when submitted and rejected if dismissed.

Example

```
$ngBootbox.prompt('Enter something')
    .then(function(result) {
        console.log('Prompt returned: ' + result);
    }, function() {
        console.log('Prompt dismissed!');
    });
```

Hope this helps. let us know.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!  This worked perfectly